# One-to-Many table relate viewed through ArcGIS Server

Tags: arcgis-server, relates, identify

I want to create a Table Relate with a one-to-many relationship between a layer and a non-spatial table based on a common field.

My question is, if I publish this data to ArcGIS Server, will an identify operation on that layer return *all* of the related values in the non-spatial table?

I want to try this, but I don't have sample data that meets these requirements (if anyone knows where I can find some, it would be very helpful).

[Here is an example from ESRI](http://blogs.esri.com/Support/blogs/esritrainingmatters/archive/2010/03/12/1104.aspx) of an Identify operation in ArcMap on two tables with a one-to-many relationship.  I need to know if the results in ArcGIS Server would be consistant.

I am using ArcGIS 10 and SQL Server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding your question about identify:  no, an identify wouldn't bring back the related records.

But you're in luck since you're using 10. You can now query via relationship classes through REST. You could use a [RelationshipQuery](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/help/jsapi/relationshipquery.htm) to find your related records. Here's a JS API sample showing how this works:  [Query related records](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/help/jssamples/fl_query_related_multiple.html)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but for a lot of methods there is a 500 row default limit, so if you have a feature related to more than 500 rows you might want to test for that.

Here's the [Query Related records REST request](http://help.arcgis.com/EN/arcgisserver/10.0/apis/rest/queryrelatedrecords.html).

Comment: I think the default was bumped up to 1000 rows at 10.